# unable to inject divs into html via javaacript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to create a simple etch a sketch game. i have started by creating a function that should inject a no. of divs into the html page but when it does. not seem to inject it for some reason.

```
let container = document.getElementById('container');

function getGrid(gridNumber) { 
for (let i = 0; i <= gridNumber * gridNumber; i++) 
{
    const row = document.createElement('div');
    row.style.border = '1px solid red'
    container.appendChild(row).classList.add('box');
}
}

getGrid(16);


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="banner"> 
    <div class="banner-text"> 
        <h1> Etch-a-Sketch </h1>
    </div>
    
</div>


<div id="container"> </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like a typo `div.style` instead of `row.style`.

Comment: just fixed that but it doesn't solve the issue. when i check elements in the console my div container does not have the injected divs

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: i have checked the console and it seems there is a type error? with "container.appendChild(row).classList.add('box');" being highlighted and the declaration of container shows null when i hover over it in the console.

Comment: Oh wait, it should be `getElementById('container') without a dot.

Comment: my current code does not have the dot. still not working...

Comment: Look, "it's not working" is not enough information to help you with. Try being more specific  Do you still get the same error? Do you have an element with `id="container"` on your HTML?

Comment: Sorry im pretty new to all of this. yes i do have an element with id="container" in it. i dont understand what else could be the issue. on the console i get this error

Comment: make sure you access 'container' *after* it has been added to dom.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')
    at getGrid (app.js:7:15)
    at app.js:11:1

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by accessing it after it has been added to the dom . i made an element tag with id = container and then targeted it in javascript and the the code

Comment: Put the `<script>` tag at the end, right above the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Yes! that worked! can you explain why?

Comment: Because the browser reads the document from top to bottom, it loads and executes the script before reading the markup below it - so before the element you referred to is created. Putting the script at the end is one way around this. Alternatively, there is also the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event, or on modern browsers the [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) attribute.

Comment: Perhaps I'll post it as an actual answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Either you do `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector`, not both.

```js
let container = document.getElementById('container');

function getGrid(gridNumber) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= gridNumber * gridNumber; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement('div');
    row.style.border = '1px solid red'
    container.appendChild(row).classList.add('box');
  }
}

getGrid(16);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: My HTML already has the targeted div with id of container. i seemed to have neglect to put that in the question will make an edit

Comment: Wait isn't it working as it should in my snippet?

Comment: your snippet seems to be working but not in my code editor. i have checked the console and it seems there is a type error? with "container.appendChild(row).classList.add('box');" being highlighted and the declaration of container shows null when i hover over it in the console.

Answer (score 0):

When the HTML parser reaches a `<script>` tag, by default the JavaScript is executed immediately - before any HTML below is being parsed. As a result, the element `<div id="container"></div>` does not exist yet when the script is looking for it and the call to `getElementById('container')` returns `null`.

- The simpler way to deal with this issue is to put any script referring to DOM elements - at the end of the HTML, right above the ending `</body>` tag.
  This appraoch, however, has a drawback when it comes to external scripts like the `app.js` in this case - the request for the file would not be sent to the server until the parser reaches the tag, so the execution of the script might be delayed.
- Another method is to make the code to wait for the [window.DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event, which fires immediately when the DOM is being fully parsed and constructed, even before other aspects of the page loading (such as fecthing images) are done.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    // any code that refers to DOM elements
});
```

This approach has the opposite drawback when it comes to external scripts - the page parsing would halt until the script is being loaded and executed.

- The third method, which is probably the best one for external script, is adding the `defer` attribute. For example:
  `<script src="app.js" defer />`
  This will cause the script to be requested asynchronously - not blocking the page loading, and also to only be executed once the DOM is being fully constructed - right before the DOMContentLoaded event is fired.